# ggplot bar plot of Total and specific category

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible in ggplot using this data:

```
months <-rep(c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", 
               "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"), 2)
chickens <-c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2)
eggs <-c(0, 8, 10, 13, 16, 20, 25, 20, 18, 16, 10, 8)
values <-c(chickens, eggs)
type <-c(rep("chickens", 12), rep("eggs", 12))
mydata <-data.frame(months, values, type)
```

Then...

```
mydata$months <-factor(mydata$months, 
                      levels = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun",
                                 "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"))
```

So then I can plot like this

```
p <-ggplot(mydata, aes(months, values))
p +geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = type), position = "dodge")
```

But instead of Chickens and Eggs I want to create a plot that shows values for Total and for "chickens" so basically you'll have a column for total and one comparing the % chickens

Something like this but only for total & chickens so I can have another plot comparing total and eggs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can first create the data to plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata %>%
  filter(type == 'chickens') %>%
  bind_rows(mydata %>%
  group_by(months) %>%
  summarise(values = sum(values), 
            type = 'total')) -> data
```

You can then use

```
ggplot(data) + aes(months, values, fill = type) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Or a stacked chart

```
ggplot(data) + aes(months, values, fill = type) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

Comment: Ronak what is happening with type = ‘total’ in the summarize function

Comment: To combine the two dataframes (one with chicken and another with totals) we need `type` column in both of them. There is already `type = 'chicken'` in one of them so we create column with `type = 'total'` in another one.